# insert data from excel into website and copy certain data onto clipboard c#

Tags: c#, excel, web

I was thinking if there is a way to code a c# app to copy and paste a large amount of data (int) from excel/notepad/word to a website which accepts only 1 int submission each time?

Because for my work, i am suppose to copy each int and paste it into a field box and submit. Then i am suppose to copy 1 of the value shown and paste it in the excel again.

So i was thinking if there is a way to create an app to paste the raw int input and it will auto generate the data that is run by the website.

For example, inputting a name in facebook search, then copy the dob of the person.

any help is greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: I think you can try `Clipboard` https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/ydby206k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 0):

You could write an app that posts the information one at a time to the site then write the value to a csv file which can then be pasted into an excel spreadsheet